# The size of char datatype in C which is in format of %s or %c?

Tags: c, types, char, sizeof, c-strings

On the internet, I found that the information of char in C programming is below:

```
Datatype        Size        Range           Format

char            1 byte     −128 to 127        %c

signed char     1 byte     −128 to 127        %c

unsigned char   1 byte        0 to 255        %c
```

But I know that there is the format %s of char (datatype), it's used to work with the string. My question is: **Is there any difference in the size and range of these 2 formats?**
Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Hoang Louis, please let me know how I can make my answer more helpful to you.

Comment: "I know that there is the format %s of char (datatype)" --> No. `"%s"` expects "a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type" like `char *`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `char` is a single character/letter, e.g. printfed with `"%c"` and e.g. a `'X'`.
What is printfed with `"%s"` is a zero-terminated string of many characters and can be given as e.g. `"foobar"`. Note the different quotation marks.
(*By the way, a common mistake when dealing with them and trying to store them is to have not enough space for the final zero. Usually one more is needed than is obvious.*)

Compare https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

The "range" of what a `%s` usually refers to is very hard to define. Could be books.

What is printfed with `%s` is sometimes described as "C pseudo-string", but there is not a datatype as such.

Answer (score 3):

Strings in C are defined like a character array that contains a sequence of characters terminated by the zero character '\0'.

For example the string literal `"Hello"` has the type `char[6]` (take into account the terminating zero character). So the operator `sizeof( "Hello" )` yields the value `6`.

The conversion specifier `%s` is designate to output strings and awaits a pointer to first character of a string. The size of a string is limited only by resources of the used system and can not be greater than the maximum value stored in the type `size_t`.

Th conversion specifier `%c` is designed to output a scalar object of the type `char`. Objects of the type `char` have the size equal to `1` (`sizeof(char )` is equal to `1`). Keep in mind that in C character literals have the type `int`. So for example sizeof( 'A' ) yields 4 (if the size of an object of the type int is equal to 4).

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "sizeof( \"Hello\" ) = %zu\n", sizeof( "Hello" ) );

    char c = 'A';

    printf( "sizeof( char ) = %zu, sizeof( 'A' ) = %zu\n", sizeof( c ), sizeof( 'A' ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
sizeof( "Hello" ) = 6
sizeof( char ) = 1, sizeof( 'A' ) = 4
```

Pay attention to that the range of values of the type `char` depends on compiler options and the type char can behave either as the type `signed char` or `unsigned char`. So it would be more correctly to write

```
char            1 byte     −128 to 127        %c
or
char            1 byte     0 to 255           %c
```

From the C Standard (5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types )

> 2 If the value of an object of type char is treated as a signed
>   integer when used in an expression, the value of CHAR_MIN shall be the
>   same as that of SCHAR_MIN and the value of CHAR_MAX shall be the same
>   as that of SCHAR_MAX. Otherwise, the value of CHAR_MIN shall be 0 and
>   the value of CHAR_MAX shall be the same as that of UCHAR_MAX. The
>   value UCHAR_MAX shall equal 2CHAR_BIT − 1.

Answer (score 1):

`%c` is used to print individual character values, and expects its corresponding argument to have type `char`:

```
char c = 'A';
printf( "%c\n", c );
```

`%s` is used to print *strings*, which are sequences of character values including a zero-valued terminator, and expects its corresponding argument to have type `char *` (pointer to `char`), which is the *address* of the first character of the string:

```
char s[] = "hello"; // equivalent to {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}
printf( “%s\n”, s ); // equivalent to passing &s[0]
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type “pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  So when we pass the *expression* `s` to `printf`, what’s actually getting passed is the address of `s[0]`, not the array contents themselves.  It’s basically equivalent to writing

```
char s[] = "hello";
char *p = s;
while ( *p != 0 )
  putchar( *p++ ); // print the character p points to, then advance
                   // p to point to the next character in the string
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no string type in C, but the C Standard Library does define strings to be null-terminated character arrays [§7.1.1p1 of the C11 Draft Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1p1)

> A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.

The table shown by OP is correct that `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are all 1 byte wide. Minimum value ranges are specified for types in the Standard, but no absolute value ranges; while the value ranges in the table are common, they are not guaranteed. In particular, it is not uncommon for `char` to be an unsigned type with a value range of 0 to 255. Note that for signed `char` types the Standard only requires a minimum range of -127 to 127. Even bytes must have a *minimum* 8 bit width, but exactly 8 bits is not specified. The actual details are implementation details.

`%c` and `%s` are used in formatted I/O operations; these are not directly related to types, but rather are used to describe for a function what types to expect. For `fprintf()` family functions the `%c` conversion specifier tells the function to expect an integer argument, which will be converted to an `unsigned char` value and printed as a character. Note that the character encoding is not required to be ASCII (this is another implementation detail), but that is far and away the most common these days.

The `%s` conversion specifier tells the `fprintf()` functions to expect a pointer to the first element of a character array. If a suitable precision is not specified (e.g. `%5s` to print at most 5 characters), the array must be a string (i.e. null-terminated).

For `fscanf()` family functions the `%c` directive tells the function to scan for one or more characters in the input (i.e. more than one when a field width is provided, as for example `%3c`), and to expect a pointer to a character array large enough to hold the results. For a simple `scanf("%c", &some_char)`, the maximum number of characters to scan is 1, and `some_char` just needs to be a `char`, e.g. defined as `char some_char;`. But for something like `scanf("%5c", five_chars)`, `five_chars` must be an array capable of storing 5 `char`s, e.g. defined as `char five_chars[5];`.

The `%s` directive operates similarly for `fscanf()` functions, but without a maximum field width specification this will tell `fscanf()` to attempt to match and store characters until a whitespace is encountered in the input. The function expects a pointer to a character array capable of holding all matched characters (plus the null-terminator), and for this reason you must always specify a maximum field width to avoid potential buffer overflow. Note also that the `%s` directive *always* causes a `\0` terminator to be written after the last character is scanned. So, when storage is declared as `char storage[100];`, it is correct to use `scanf("%99s", storage);`. This tells `scanf()` to match *at most* 99 characters in the input before writing a final `\0`, avoiding writing past the end of the `storage[]` array in cases of large input.

There are more details about [`fprintf()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1) and [`fscanf()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2). Note that `fscanf()` in particular is a complicated function that is tricky to use correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`%s` and `%c` are not formats or types. They are called "conversion or format *specifiers*", used for the correct formatting regarding one of the character types or a string, used by functions of the `printf()` and`scanf()` families. Thus, *they* have no "size" or "range" on their own.

---

> Is there any difference in the size and range of these 2 formats?

In C, a string is not a type on its own. A string is a contiguous sequence of character objects.

The "size" of a string is determined in the source code or while the program is running ([variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)); there is no general fixed size for a string.

A string has nothing like a "range" in that manner it has a character or integer type.

You trying to ask if all of those characters together (can) provide a greater range. The answer is simply no.

All characters inside of a string have their own dedicated range and size in memory, You can not see them as a kind of compound with which you can store and represent greater values:

```
char a;
```

`a` has the size of 1 byte and the range of −128 to 127 or 0 to 255 (depends on the implementation and platform but on most modern systems it will have the range of -128 to 127).

```
char b[4];
```

`b` has the size of 4 byte in this case, but the range of it is not from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (2³² = 4,294,967,296 storable values (Note one bit for the sign representation)). It is only consisted of 4 `char` objects with each of those have 1 byte allocated in memory and can store/represent values from −128 to 127/0 to 255.

If you want to use a wider range for a single character, use the wide character type `wchar_t`.